# Dealing with optional confirmation dialogs in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I want to handle confirmation dialogs in Selenium IDE, but whether or not they launch is controlled by internal logic which is not clear to the user; hence if I put a 'storeConfirmation' or similar. It works if there is a confirmation dialog but fails if there isn't one, and vice versa if I don't add a check.

'chooseOkOnNextConfirmation' does not work; "Error: There was an unexpected confirmation".

Has anyone faced this issue before?

Thanks

Comment: "controlled by internal logic which is not clear to user" is almost always bad testing technique. Someone should know the logic of the site you are about to test

Comment: poor wording.  The key is; that it may or may not require a confirmation dialogue and there is no way to determine this simply, nor is it even relevant.  The point is simply that I want any confirmation dialogs to be confirmed.  Hopefully that makes it clearer.